# Using flowplayer autoplay true is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, flowplayer

I'm in PHP website. Am trying to play the video automatically in the flowplayer. but it is not working and not giving any problem

```
$(function(){
      // Top Stories videos
      var topStoriesVideos = [
        {
            sources: [
              {
                  type: 'video/mp4',
                  src:  "https://storage.googleapis.com/web-assets/videos/Youarewatchingtrd/ad2/Ad2/Ad2-360p.mp4"
              }
          ]
        },

      ];       
      PlaylistApi = flowplayer("#tv",  { autoPlay: true,
          playlist: topStoriesVideos,
      });

    })
   flowplayer(function (api, root) { 

  api.on("load", function () {

  }).on("ready", function () {

 history.replaceState({}, '', x[count++]);
  });

api.bind("finish", function(){

  });

$("#pause").click(function(){
    api.pause(function(){     
    })
})

});
```

I tried clip:{autoplay: true,},
But it is also not working

Answer (score 0):

It should be `autoplay: true` instead of `autoPlay: true`
The 'P' shouldn't be capitalized.